# tensorflow_model_server error while loading shared libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow, shared-libraries, tensorflow-serving

I've trained a Keras model on a GPU, converted it to a TF estimator, then exported the estimator for TF serving with `export_savedmodel`.

I can successfully serve this model on a GPU machine, but what I'd like to do is serve it on a CPU. When I try to serve on a CPU-only instance, I get the error:

`tensorflow_model_server: error while loading shared libraries: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I'm not sure why Tensorflow serving is looking for CUDA on a CPU instance. Is it TF serving that is looking for CUDA or is it my exported model that is looking for a GPU device because that's what it was trained with?

Comment: How are you installing tensorflow-serving? Where are you getting the build from?

Comment: SageMaker, their official docker image for the combination of tf version, python version, and hardware type is pulled from their ECR repo

Comment: Should be this: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container/blob/master/docker/1.12/Dockerfile.cpu so this should be using the dockerhub tensorflow/serving:1.12.0 which isn't GPU tagged.

Comment: The devices are indeed saved in the model. I see they have a clear_devices=True flag to prevent the devices from being saved in the model, although I'm not sure where in the keras to estimator to export flow it belongs. Can you post your code?

Comment: I got it figured out, it turns out it was a bug. Was pulling the gpu docker image even though i specified a cpu instance type.